# Streaming from Raspberry Pi with wireless connection without connecting to the internet

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am new with Raspberry Pi, I want to make video streaming from Raspberry Pi to the laptop without connecting to the internet and with wireless connection.

I want to know what is the best way to do this, what I have understood while searching the internet, that there is two ways:

1. making ad hoc network
2. making an access point from laptop and connecting to it

I have not understood much about them and how to use them and if there is any other ways.

Could anybody summarize the ways of wireless connection and which is the best one for streaming?

And if there is good links for tutorials will be great :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Streaming, there is a software called "motion".
ad-hoc is not that stable, you need a network switch in order to get good performance.
keep in mind that you can use routers too as they have already the switch functionality if you have one already.